# ember.js making your variables accesssable from childroutes

Tags: javascript, ember.js

i'm new at ember.js and i worked out the guide and read a lot of stuf. I've got a simple(?) problem, but i cant see the light :)

So I try to programm a questionnaire.

My idea is, i make the controll of the questionnaire on the mainpage (called kalkulator) and save the variables on this page too. Because at the last outline side i want to calculate the result.

My question is saving the variables at the index the right strategy?

I tried it, but i fail on the first side of my questionnaire, i cannot access at the variable from the mainpage kalkulator.

```
App.AgentverteilungController = Ember.Controller.extend({

    needs: "kalkulator"
});



  <script type="text/x-handlebars" id="agentverteilung">
      <ul>
        question...
          {{input type="text" value=kalkulator.variable size="4"}}
          Inserted: {{kalkulator.variable }}
      </ul>
  </script>
```

I hope somebody can help me.  Thanks for advices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now, your needs variable is a string when it should be an array change

```
needs: "kalkulator"
```

to

```
needs: ['kalkulator']
```

Secondly, in handlebars when you need to access a controller you've included, you get to it through the **controllers** variable. For example:

```
{{kalkulator.variable}}
```

should be

```
{{controllers.kalkulator.variable}}
```